# MVC redirect if ViewBag.Elements is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, model-view-controller, controller

I want that if someone is going to my page and the ViewBag.Elements is null, then redirect to HomeController Index.
I guess I have to do this in BaseController somehow, because I want this anytime and any page open. I mean if someone is going to a specific url of my site too (e.g. mysite:1234/Test/Index)

Thank you for your help in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, googled a lot and tried few things, like in the base initialize RedirectToAction, or call with ControllerContext or rewrite HttpContext.Response.Redirect but not working any of these

Comment: if you're checking it in the controller, it will pretty much always be null.. since that is where you typically set the value

Comment: No it's not.
And now I found a bit deeper root cause of the issue.
Looks it can be ok with override void OnActionExecuting and filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(Url.Action

BUT not with the conroller and Action I set, because it causes infinite loop...

Comment: What you would like to do if the user hit the URL for home index and Viewbag is empty ?

Comment: Looks the issue was with the ViewBag itself!
If I'm using TempData instead of ViewBag, it works well!

Thanks all!